# Xamarin forms splash screen visible navigate to another page

Tags: xamarin.forms

The splash screen is visible when navigating to a new page in xamarin.forms android. I want to remove or hide the image.

Here is my *style.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash_</item> 
 </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Is the new page background transparent?

Comment: Please write in full sentences.

Comment: i didnot set any background image.

Comment: Are you still using `MyTheme.Splash` for your main activity?

Answer (score 0):

In you have activity for the splash, then add 'NoHistory=true' in the activity attribute. Sample below,

```
[Activity(Label = "XXXX", MainLauncher =true, Theme = "@style/Splash", NoHistory =true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Your solution with "NoHistory=true" is not working for me